# Unhandled exception type ParseException - Parse.com Example Implementation

Tags: java, android, parsing, rest

I'm attempting to expand my current source code to include additional rows of data (it works fine using just the textview: empty) however when I attempt to add empty2 to allow for more data to be displayed - I'm running into the error:

"Empty2 Cannot Be Resolved Or Is Not A Field"

Even though I've created a textview called empty2

Any idea why this might be happening?

todo_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5sp"
    android:textSize="25sp" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/android:empty2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/empty" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/android:empty3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/empty" />
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/android:empty4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/empty" />
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/android:empty5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/empty" />

</TextView>



package com.parse.demo;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;

public class ToDoListActivity extends ListActivity {
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE = 0;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT = 1;

    public static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;

    private List<ParseObject> todos;
    private Dialog progressDialog;

    private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        // Override this method to do custom remote calls
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Gets the current list of todos in sorted order
            ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("TestObject");
            query.orderByDescending("_created_at");

            try {
                todos = query.find();
            } catch (ParseException e) {

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            ToDoListActivity.this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ToDoListActivity.this, "",
                    "Loading...", true);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Put the list of todos into the list view
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ToDoListActivity.this,
                    R.layout.todo_row);
            for (ParseObject todo : todos) {
                adapter.add((String) todo.get("DataI"));
                adapter.add((String) todo.get("DataO"));
            }
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            ToDoListActivity.this.progressDialog.dismiss();
            TextView empty = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
            TextView empty2 = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.empty2);
            empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            empty2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView empty = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
        empty.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        TextView empty2 = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.empty2);
        empty2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        new RemoteDataTask().execute();
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    }

    private void createTodo() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, CreateTodo.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (intent == null) {
            return;
        }
        final Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        switch (requestCode) {
        case ACTIVITY_CREATE:
            new RemoteDataTask() {
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    String DataI = extras.getString("DataI");
                    String DataO = extras.getString("DataO");
                    ParseObject todo = new ParseObject("Todo");
                    todo.put("DataI", DataI);
                    todo.put("DataO", DataO);
                    try {
                        todo.save();
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                    }

                    super.doInBackground();
                    return null;
                }
            }.execute();
            break;
        case ACTIVITY_EDIT:
            // Edit the remote object
            final ParseObject todo;
            todo = todos.get(extras.getInt("position"));
            todo.put("DataI", extras.getString("DataI"));
            todo.put("DataO", extras.getString("DataO"));

            new RemoteDataTask() {
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {
                        todo.save();
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                    }
                    super.doInBackground();
                    return null;
                }
            }.execute();
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        boolean result = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_insert);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case DELETE_ID:
            AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

            // Delete the remote object
            final ParseObject todo = todos.get(info.position);


            new RemoteDataTask() {
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {
                        todo.delete();
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                    }
                    super.doInBackground();
                    return null;
                }
            }.execute();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case INSERT_ID:
            createTodo();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, CreateTodo.class);

        i.putExtra("DataI", todos.get(position).getString("DataI").toString());
        i.putExtra("DataO", todos.get(position).getString("DataO").toString());
        i.putExtra("position", position);


        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
    }

}
```

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/empty" />
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/android:empty2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/empty" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/android:empty3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/empty" />
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/android:empty4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/empty" />
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/android:empty5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/empty" />
</LinearLayout>
```

SOURCE AFTER ANSWER EDITS:

```
import java.util.List;

import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ToDoListActivity extends ListActivity {


    TextView empty;
    TextView empty2;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE = 0;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT = 1;

    public static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;

    private List<ParseObject> todos;
    private Dialog progressDialog;

    private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        // Override this method to do custom remote calls
        public void setVisibility() {
               empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               empty2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  

        }
        protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Gets the current list of todos in sorted order
            ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("TestObject");
            query.orderByDescending("_created_at");

            try {
                todos = query.find();
            } catch (ParseException e) {

                return;

            }




            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {


            //      
                   }});
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            ToDoListActivity.this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ToDoListActivity.this, "",
                    "Loading...", true);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Put the list of todos into the list view
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ToDoListActivity.this,
                    R.layout.todo_row);
            for (ParseObject todo : todos) {
                adapter.add((String) todo.get("DataI"));
                adapter.add((String) todo.get("DataO"));
                adapter.add((String) todo.get("DataRSSI"));
                adapter.add((String) todo.get("DataSSID"));
                adapter.add((String) todo.get("DataTIME"));
                adapter.add((String) todo.get("DataRESTRICTED"));
            }
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            ToDoListActivity.this.progressDialog.dismiss();
        //  TextView empty = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
    //      empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_new);

            empty = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
            empty.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        //    empty2 = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.empty2);
         //   empty2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        new RemoteDataTask().execute();
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    }

    private void createTodo() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, CreateTodo.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (intent == null) {
            return;
        }
        final Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        switch (requestCode) {
        case ACTIVITY_CREATE:
            new RemoteDataTask() {
                protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    String DataI = extras.getString("DataI");
                    String DataO = extras.getString("DataO");
                    String DataRSSI = extras.getString("DataRSSI");
                    String DataSSID = extras.getString("DataSSID");
                    String DataTIME = extras.getString("DataTIME");
                    String DataRESTRICTED = extras.getString("DataRESTRICTED");
                    ParseObject todo = new ParseObject("Todo");
                    todo.put("DataI", DataI);
                    todo.put("DataO", DataO);
                    todo.put("DataRSSI", DataRSSI);
                    todo.put("DataSSID", DataSSID);
                    todo.put("DataTIME", DataTIME);
                    todo.put("DataRESTRICTED", DataRESTRICTED);
                    try { todo.save(); } catch (ParseException e) {
                    }

                    super.doInBackground();
                    return;
                }
            }.execute();
            break;
        case ACTIVITY_EDIT:
            // Edit the remote object
            final ParseObject todo;
            todo = todos.get(extras.getInt("position"));
            todo.put("DataI", extras.getString("DataI"));
            todo.put("DataO", extras.getString("DataO"));
            todo.put("DataRSSI", extras.getString("DataRSSI"));
            todo.put("DataSSID", extras.getString("DataSSID"));
            todo.put("DataTIME", extras.getString("DataTIME"));
            todo.put("DataRESTRICTED", extras.getString("DataRESTRICTED"));

            new RemoteDataTask() {
                protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {
                        todo.save();
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                    }
                    super.doInBackground();
                    return;
                }
            }.execute();
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        boolean result = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_insert);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case DELETE_ID:
            AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

            // Delete the remote object
            final ParseObject todo = todos.get(info.position);


            new RemoteDataTask() {
                protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {
                        todo.delete();
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                    }
                    super.doInBackground();
                    return;
                }
            }.execute();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case INSERT_ID:
            createTodo();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, CreateTodo.class);

        i.putExtra("DataI", todos.get(position).getString("DataI").toString());
        i.putExtra("DataO", todos.get(position).getString("DataO").toString());
        i.putExtra("DataRSSI", todos.get(position).getString("DataRSSI").toString());
        i.putExtra("DataSSID", todos.get(position).getString("DataSSID").toString());
        i.putExtra("DataTIME", todos.get(position).getString("DataTIME").toString());
        i.putExtra("DataRESTRICTED", todos.get(position).getString("DataRESTRICTED").toString());
        i.putExtra("position", position);


        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
    }

}
```

PROBLEMS

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Void methods cannot return a value  ToDoListActivity.java   /NFC Linking Manager/src/com/nfc/linkingmanager line 56 Java Problem
The return type is incompatible with AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>.doInBackground(Void[])   ToDoListActivity.java   /NFC Linking Manager/src/com/nfc/linkingmanager line 47 Java Problem
```

Comment: You cannot call `TextView empty2 = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.empty2);` within an AsyncTask. Instead you should `onPostExecute(...)` invoke a method in the calling Activity to change View visibility or whatever else you wish you do.

Comment: How can this be implemented? (Im quite new to Android Development - this is my first app)

Comment: Doesnt the line: empty2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); in the onPostExecute(...)  already handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are updating the UI, you will need to use the `runOnUiThread(...)` method within the `AsyncTask`.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      setVisibility();
   }
});
```

Where you would need to define the `setVisibility()` method in the `ToDoListActivity` Activity. 
eg.

```
setVisibility() {
   empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   empty2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Also, it is best to declare the UI objects in the global scope and instantiate then in the `onCreate(...)` method. 
eg.

```
public class ToDoListActivity extends ListActivity {
   ...
   TextView empty;
   TextView empty2;
   ...
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    empty = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
    empty.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    empty2 = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.empty2);
    empty2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**

You need to modify the `onPostExecute(...)` method in the AsyncTask as below:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
// Put the list of todos into the list view
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ToDoListActivity.this,
        R.layout.todo_row);
for (ParseObject todo : todos) {
    adapter.add((String) todo.get("DataI"));
    adapter.add((String) todo.get("DataO"));
    adapter.add((String) todo.get("DataRSSI"));
    adapter.add((String) todo.get("DataSSID"));
    adapter.add((String) todo.get("DataTIME"));
    adapter.add((String) todo.get("DataRESTRICTED"));
}
setListAdapter(adapter);
ToDoListActivity.this.progressDialog.dismiss();
/* REMOVE BELOW LINES */
//TextView empty = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
//empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//TextView empty2 = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.empty2);
//empty2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

}

As well as the `runOnUiThread(...)` method

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
  setVisibility();
  /* REMOVE BELOW LINES */
  //empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  //empty2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
});
```

And I do not see the `setVisibility()` method in your `ToDoListActivity` class.

**UPDATE**

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Gets the current list of todos in sorted order
        ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("TestObject");
        query.orderByDescending("_created_at");

        try {
            todos = query.find();
        } catch (ParseException e) {

        }

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                  setVisibility();
               }});

        return null; // RETURN STATEMENT HERE
    }
```

Comment: I edited my source code above to include the Run On UI Thread but I'm getting several errors (in eclipse) regarding it's implementation : ( 


(I must have done something wrong)

Comment: Can you post the error logs. Also, you did not remove the code in `onPostExecute(...)` where the TextViews are changed. Also, no `setVisibility()` method definition in Activity, among other things.

Comment: All issues are resolved except " unreachable code on my runonuithread" : )

Comment: I edited my source code : ) [thanks again for helping me with this]

I'm still getting 3 errors though : ( 

[I added my problems log above]

Comment: Refer to `EDIT 2` in answer.

Comment: Eclipse now states there is a syntax error on it and to remove "void", I also still have return type missing for setVisibility at the line: private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  // Override this method to do custom remote calls
  setVisibility() {


...and the method Set Visibility is undefined for the type runnable at: 

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
          setVisibility();
       
     return void;

Comment: I updated my souce and problems log (I cannot thank you enough for this - I REALLY need to get this portion up and running)

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to add    setVisibility(); after public class ToDoListActivity extends ListActivity { but that isn't working either

Comment: Got it down to one error...


Description Resource Path Location Type
This method must return a result of type Void ToDoListActivity.java /ToDoList/src/com/parse/demo line 46 Java Problem

Comment: add a `return null` at the very end of the `doInBackground(...)` method

Comment: You are going to kill me... 

I made all the changes you suggested - and Eclipse is still showing errors in the source code (updated above)

Comment: Check updated answer, again. I would suggest reading the Android documentation provided by Google to get a better understanding of the application flow. Also, try following the error logs as they have line numbers and methods where it crashed. Debugging will improve your skills the most. And glad to help, I hate when I can't get things to work either.

Comment: just one error left... (it was an import issue - I used an import by the same name but outside of the parse.com package) similar to the error I was having on line 41 - however protected void doInBackground(Void... params) { looks correct - with the exception of the capital V - should that be lowercase?

Comment: I am SO sorry... I must be driving you insane. (I added it - it gave me a new error stating Void methods cannot return a value when placing it at the following line:

protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
   ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("TestObject");
   query.orderByDescending("_created_at");
   
   try {
    todos = query.find();
   } catch (ParseException e) {

    return null;
    
   }

Comment: commenting it out removes the error... which simply leaves me with:

Description Resource Path Location Type
The return type is incompatible with AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>.doInBackground(Void[]) ToDoListActivity.java  line 47 Java Problem

Comment: If I leave return null; I get void methods cannot return a value - if I comment it out - it disappears - but no matter what I do: I'm stuck with The return type is incompatible with AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>.doInBackground(Void[]) [the only error left in my log]

Comment: We are SO close to getting this resolved... I cannot thank you enough!

Comment: lol did you change `return void` to `return null` in the doInBackgroun(...) method and move the return to the end of the method?

Comment: adding return null leaves me with errors - the only way to resolve it is simply return; 

but I'm still left with Description Resource Path Location Type
The return type is incompatible with AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>.doInBackground(Void[]) ToDoListActivity.java  line 47 Java Problem

Comment: [Updated source above - just that one error left - and yes I move it to (what appears to me to be) the end]

Comment: I am losing my mind trying to figure this out... (it seems like I'm stuck in a catch 22 in implementing your final suggestion - it gives an error if I do - and an error if I dont - I REALLY need to get this up and running [the server side code is the last thing I need to implement before turning this project in today]

Comment: check update for return statement. There are design problems and possibly other things that should be changed. I would read over Android documentation and best way to learn is to write failing code until it works.